# Unable to deduce properties have come from the same constituent of a union

Tags: typescript

I've noticed an issue with union types in TypeScript, which I believe is not solvable without a type assertion or `// @ts-expect-error`. When I extract two fields from the same object, which is of a union type, TypeScript is unable to logically deduce that they must have come from the same constituent of that union (and as such, that they may be incompatible).

I've reduced this to a simple example here. My actual use-case has many more types in the union than 2.

```js
interface Animal<Noise> {
  noise: Noise;
  makeNoise: (params: Noise) => void;
}

type Cat = Animal<'meow'>;
type Dog = Animal<'woof'>;
const pet = {} as Cat | Dog;
const { noise, makeNoise } = pet;

// we get a type error here
makeNoise(noise);
```

Does anyone know a way to robustly resolve this type of issue without needed to override or ignore it?

Comment: It may look redundant, but the official recommendation is to solve this kind of problem in [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKb9om). Does it work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hey @wonderflame - thanks for this! I'd gone down a similar approach but given up as it seemed a bit silly.

My actually problem is a fair bit more complex than this example, but your suggestion fixes this example and provided enough inspiration for me to fix my more complex case too :)

Comment: In fact, I managed to make it a little more concise by just accessing `Pets[T]` rather than having to create a function type, like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgGwDwByA9sAM4QB8yA3gFDLIgnkBcyxZEA3PctgNYQOrZAAoADnChxMpNsIgBKZAF4qANxIATHgF9atMAE9xKAAoQwAWTjjVNXgjhg2AckwQiAd1c8GWogBzNy8iIhhfWl0eQxNzS1J7OgYAbQBpZFBkQSNw5AtrWwBdNnQsXDwCm3F0ooo9GIQiEFIwZCccHBtBBXs8ABVkCAAPSBAtRJy8qtsKCUs2AtIU-qLlNQcGUzAAOgEhZgh53aZORQaDY1NkAGFneyWU1ycwVyKeK5QAESCHhKeAoE3o1mq1kNskrpkHBEnc2gAfZA-QKNXBdOA9Q7Hc60IA)